# how to specify entry type on front end entry form?

Tags: entry-type, entry-form

I have a section with 2 entry types. Logged in users need to be able to submit to each type. I had planned on having 2 different entry forms.

How do I tell the form which entry type to save to? I assume it's a hidden field but what's the field name and where do I find the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify a hidden input with the `typeId` set correctly.

i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="typeId" value="{{ entry.typeId }}">
```